# How to check if a category has a parent category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to check if 'categoryone' has a parent.
Right know I can check and see that there is a category called categoryone, but not if categoryone has a parent category.
I have tried to code something like the code bellow.

```
  $tid = term_exists('categoryone', 'category', 0);

  $term_ids = [];

  if ( $tid !== 0 && $tid !== null )
  {
$term_ids[] = $tid['term_id'];

  }
  else
  {
    // If there is not a parent category!
    $insert_term_id = wp_insert_term( 'categoryone', 'category' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error )
    $term_ids[] = $insert_term_id;
  }
  wp_set_post_categories( $insert_id, $term_ids );
```

Answer (score 25):

You may use something like this (Paste this in your `functions.php` file)

```
function category_has_parent($catid){
    $category = get_category($catid);
    if ($category->category_parent > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call this from template

```
if(category_has_parent($tid)) {
    // it has a parent
}
```

Check Children

```
function has_Children($cat_id)
{
    $children = get_terms(
        'category',
        array( 'parent' => $cat_id, 'hide_empty' => false )
    );
    if ($children){
        return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

Call this from template

```
if(has_Children($tid)) {
    // it has children
}
```

Comment: Nice code, but Is it possible to check if 'categoryone' has Childe categories to?

Comment: Yes, definitely, hold on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**get_category()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) to fetch current category details by passing term_id

```
$tid = term_exists('categoryone', 'category', 0);
$t_details=get_category($tid);
if(!empty($t_details->parent)){
echo $t_details->parent; // parent category id or $t_details->category_parent
}
```

[get_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) returns the object like below taken from reference site

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 85
    [name] => Category Name
    [slug] => category-name
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 85
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 70
    [count] => 0
    [cat_ID] => 85
    [category_count] => 0
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Category Name
    [category_nicename] => category-name
    [category_parent] => 70
)
```

**EDIT** To get the child categories you can use [**get_categories()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) by passing the the arguments array.

**parent**

> (integer) Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e.
>   children only) of the category identified by its ID

```
$args=array('parent'=>$tid);
$child_categories=get_categories($args);
```

Comment: Super like you code! Is it possible to check if 'categoryone' has Childe categories to?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use [`get_category_parents()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) (take a look at the link to read over the arguments, etc). This will return a list of all the parents in hierarchical order. In that case, if you just want the most immediate parent category you could do something like this:

```
<?php 
 $parent_cats = get_category_parents( $cat, false, ',' ); 
 $parent_cat = explode(",", $parent_cats); 
 echo $parent_cat[0];    
?>
```

This will echo out the 1st parent category (the one directly above your current category).

To be clear:

in `get_category_parents()`
 
- arg 1 is the category id (i just used `$cat` arbitrarily)
- arg 2 is if you would like wp to add a link to each returned parent category
- arg 3 is the delimiter used to separate the returned categories, if any

in `explode()`
- arg 1 is the delimiter to look for to separate the string in an array
- arg 2 is the source string to separate

Happy coding!

Comment: Nice, code... Is it possible to check if 'categoryone' has Childe categories?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to check parent and children of a category.

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); // get current term

$parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') ); // get parent term

$children = get_term_children($term->term_id, get_query_var('taxonomy')); // get children

if(($parent->term_id!="" && sizeof($children)>0)) {

   // has parent and child

}elseif(($parent->term_id!="") && (sizeof($children)==0)) {

   // has parent, no child

}elseif(($parent->term_id=="") && (sizeof($children)>0)) {

   // no parent, has child

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ M Khalid Junaid

To expand on your answer, I used the basis of your code to check if it the category has no parents and is a top tier item in a category/taxonomy heriarchy. I am including this because it is what I was looking for when I stumbled across this thread and maybe someone else is doing the same.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'taxonomy' = 'categories'; // If using custom post types, type in the custom post type's name
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $has_parent = $term->parent;
    $name = $term->name;

    // If it doesn't have parents...
    if ( !$has_parent ) {

        // ...then it's the top tier in a hierarchy!
        echo "Tier 1:" $name . '<br />';

    }
}
?>
```

### Output

Tier 1: Category Name
Tier 1: Another Category Name
Tier 1: All Top Level Categories

Answer (score 0):

```
$queried = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    if ($queried->category_parent) {
        // category has parent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, get all the terms under your taxonomy 'taxonomy_name' and
>   then check each of them has parent or not.
>   Try out the code below

```
<?php
$service_terms= get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name'
) );
?>
<?php if(!empty($service_terms)) : ?>
   <?php foreach($service_terms as $term) : ?>
        <?php $has_parent = $term->parent; ?>
        <?php if (!$has_parent): ?>
                      <!-- If this term is a parent then put your code here -->
        <?php endif ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```